# Append custom information to a JSF error message from Message.Properties file

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Can anyone explain how to append information to a default error message thrown from 'message.properties' file in jsf.

My application is setup in such a way that When I enter number 0 instead of any number in a inputText field, I am getting the following error message from message.properties file.

**Current functionality:**

Validation Error: Value is less than allowable minimum of '1'

But, i want to display the error message on the webpage as follows

**Desired functionality:**

Validation Error: Value is less than allowable minimum of '1' for the user XYZ

Basically, I want to get the username which is available on the same page where I am entering the number and append this username to the error message in the event of any error. The username will be changing for each user and it is not constant. I am not sure if I can override the message.properties file in this case and write my own error message because the user name will be changing and dynamic.

```
<f:validateLongRange minimum="1"/>
```

I am using the above code to validate the input text..

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this using the default JSF validators, I'm afraid you need to write your own. You can override the default JSF error messages:

https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/user-friendly-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2/

but I don't know how to pass more information into them.

Comment: Take a look at this article about custom JSF validators:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_customvalidator_tag.htm